# What is Lock in Python _thread module?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I read "Core Python Applications Programming", in which this code is written.

```py
import _thread
from time import sleep, ctime

loops = [4, 2]

def loop(nloop, nsec, lock):
  print("start loop", nloop, "at:", ctime())
  sleep(nsec)
  print("loop", nloop, "done at:", ctime())
  lock.release()

def main():
  print("starting at:", ctime())
  locks = []
  nloops = range(len(loops))

  for i in nloops:
    lock = _thread.allocate_lock()
    a = lock.acquire()
    locks.append(lock)

  for i in nloops:
    _thread.start_new_thread(loop, (i, loops[i], locks[i]))

  for i in nloops:
    while locks[i].locked(): pass

  print("all DONE at:", ctime())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

In official reference, I saw "only one thread at a time can acquire a lock".
Lock is to ensure that only one thread is executed at a time, isn't it ?
Now I have two questions.

1. Why can more than one locks be produced ?
2. Why can two thread acquire each lock at the same time ?

Comment: You should allocate only **one** lock, and should be acquired, released in thread function.

Comment: Please ask each question in its own question, not together.

Comment: "Lock is to ensure that only one thread is executed at a time, isn't it ?" No. Lock is to ensure that only one thread who acquired the lock is allowed to execute the code block wrapped up by that lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re (1), you can make as many locks as you require -- presumably they're needed to protect different shared mutable resources in a many-threads environment (personally, I think a programming environment with many threads sharing many mutable resources is where programmers go after passing if they've led really terrible lives).

Re (2), "Why can two thread acquire each lock at the same time" -- they absolutely **cannot**, that is all that locks are about: that each lock can be held by at most one thread at any given time.  The lock object is built that way using whatever underlying resources the operating system provides for the purpose.

Comment: I added this code after acquiring locks.   for i in nloops: locks[i].locked()       and they return True. Why ? GIL makes only a thread executable at a time isn't it?

Comment: @q2ven yes to gil, but irrelevant.  All locks are locked but that doesn't tell you by **which** thread they're held.

Comment: You mean Lock of thread and threading module and Global Lock are irrelevant ? I thought they were the same. Thank you and sorry my bad English.

Comment: There is one Global Interpreter Lock to protect all the Python runtime's internal resources.  That's completely distinct from locks you make with the `_tread` module to protect whatever specific application resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My cobwebs were blown away. I will search for more information about GIL and Multithreading in Python. If possible, would you tell me the web sites written about details of the concepts?

Comment: @q2ven, http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf , http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/03/31/pythons-hardest-problem/ , https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock , http://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/ , http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm -- now you'd better accept my answer (clic on the outline checkmark to the left of the answer) or nobody will ever bother any more to provide you with a zillion links at your request!-)

Comment: This is my first question and I did not know the checkmark. I clicked. I appreciate your many kindnesses to me.